# Use Vim for git commit --amend

Tags: git, vim, windows-terminal

I'm using Windows Terminal, when I run `git commit --amend`, the Nano editor is displayed. How do I change it to use Vim instead? (With Git Bash, it uses Vim.)

Answer (score 2):

Set in your [`.gitconfig`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration):

```sh
[core]
        editor = 'vi'
```

You can also set through

```
git config --global core.editor vi
```